# how to build a hmm model with strings as the observation sequence?

Tags: python, hmmlearn

I have checked lots of examples and found out for python `hmmlearn` library, the sequence to be put into `model.fit()` must be a list of numbers, if I have a string list as the input, i need to convert it into a number list first.

**However**, if I have two states, 8 observation letters with two groups: vowel and consonant shown as below,

my model result should give me 8*2 emission matrix(8 => 8 letters; 2 => vowel and consonant states)

What should I put in the `model.fit()`?? How should I build the general hmm model? Any one have any idea??

```
states=["vowel","consonant"]
obs=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is easy, just to convert observation sequences to numbers will do, i failed to get result just due to the unknown reason of my Jupyter notebook enovironment, not the code itself!

Comment: Hello ! 

Could you provide some codes to understand a bit better your answer ? :)